# Do Opera extensions support notifications and background mode?

Tags: opera-extension

Does Opera api support `notifications` and `background` in the manifest file?
When I load extension, I get:

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>   Permission 'notifications' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
>   Permission 'background' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.

How to implement desktop notifications in a Opera extension?
Does Opera support background apps/extensions mode like Google Chrome?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opera doesn't support desktop notifications and background mode at this point.
https://twitter.com/andreasbovens/status/428461696584519680